# Forward slash causing errors in Javascript/JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm new to Javascript and JSX and have run into an issue regarding the forward slash key.
JSX uses forward slashes to close tags, example: `<div className="container">Hello World!</div>`

My issue is, whenever I type a single forward slash `/`, my text editors read the rest of the line as string value.  (Or at least color-codes it the same color as string).

The issue has appeared in Sublime Text 3 and Brackets.  I've checked the build version of each and they're both stable.

I reproduced the issue with a simple box generator.  This is the html, and below it is the link to the Javascript file in question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- React refs -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.3/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.3/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

    <!-- Babel/JSXTransformer ref -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .box {
            padding: 6px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 2px solid coral;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .container {
            margin: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="component1"></div>
    <div class="container" id="component2"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="forwardSlash.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here is where the problem lies, on the last two lines:
[forwardSlash.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4ByE.png)**

These two files generate a green box on top.  Then randomly generate a red or blue box below it...except the `/` is preventing the rest of the line to execute properly...so no blue or red box is displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've scoured the interwebs and spoken to other developers, but no one can seem to help.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question, not as an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <GreenBox />
), document.getElementById('component1'));
```

Note the first arg of `.render` is a wrapper around the element, when entered directly.  Or, you could do this:

```
const greenBoxDOM = (
    <div>
      <Box color="green"></Box>
    </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    greenBoxDOM,
    document.getElementById('component1')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is, whenever I type a single forward slash /, my text editors
>   read the rest of the line as string value. (Or at least color-codes it
>   the same color as string).

This is because you are writing the code in JSX but the syntax highlighting is being done for pure JavaScript.
For Sublime Text, you will have to install a package for it named Babel.
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel
they have mentioned how to enable it after installing.

There must be some similar package for Brackets too.

Comment: Thanks, your link helped fix the sublime text highlighting issue.  I'll find out tomorrow if Brackets has any jsx support